# uploadPart is failing with Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to perform a file upload using multipart upload AWS S3 java API (I am using SDK 1.8.1).
I am able to perform the upload successfully.

But, intermittently I keep getting this exception.

> Jul 31, 2014 4:39:38 AM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient
>   executeHelper INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189) at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121) at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:312) at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:350) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
>   at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102) at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:66)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:717)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:522)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:402)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:245)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3711)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadPart(AmazonS3Client.java:2809)
>   at cloud.<-filename->.writeContent(<-filename->.java:<-linenumber->)

at the following code

```
try {
                  _partETags.add(_s3.uploadPart(uploadPartReq).getPartETag());
      } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
                  System.out.println("Amazon service error. Retrying...");
                  printException(e);
      } catch (Exception e) {
                  printException(e);
                  throw new UserException("Received an exception while performing upload part");
      }
```

If I look at the docuementation, it says that uploadPart function will throw only two classes AmazonClientException and AmazonServiceException.

Link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#uploadPart(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.UploadPartRequest)

> ```
> <documentation>
> ...
> UploadPartResult uploadPart(UploadPartRequest request)
> throws AmazonClientException,
> AmazonServiceException
> ...
> Throws:
> AmazonClientException - If any errors are encountered in the client while making the request or handling the response.
> AmazonServiceException - If any errors occurred in Amazon S3 while processing the request. 
> ...
> </documentation>
> ```

But, I am receiving at different exception.

I have the following questions

- Is this an expected behavior, if not how do I fix this issue?
- Why is my try catch block not able to catch this exception ?
- In the case of AmazonClient or AmazonServiceException, is it recommended that we
  retry the upload again or should these be considered as
  non-recoverable errors ?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing

Answer (score 1):

That's a log message (at the INFO level) from the AmazonS3Client telling you there was a transient network error. By default, the AmazonS3Client catches these kinds of exceptions and retries the upload for you. You can tweak this behavior via [ClientConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#setRetryPolicy(com.amazonaws.retry.RetryPolicy)). If the upload has still not succeeded after the configured number of retries, an `AmazonClientException` will be thrown, as per the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

While i was trying to upload my project AWS lambda via eclipse, I followed the steps from the tutorial link:

> > > https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/software-development/amazon-aws/tutorial-use-aws-lambda-s3-real-time-data-processing/

But while working on the step "Deploy Lambda code to AWS"  ===>
In Eclipse, right click your code and select Amazon Web Services > Upload function to Lambda…

**Errors I faced :** 
1) I got an error window with the message "*Failed to upload project to Lambda  Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error*"

2) First Line of my Stack Tarce for an exception was :
"*com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error*"

3) Eclipse error log was giving the message : "java.lang.NullPointerException   at org.eclipse.core.databinding.ValueBinding.doUpdate(ValueBinding.java:158)"

Then i changed the setting by making a small change in my eclipse network connection, since my proxy setting was blocking to upload my project to lambda, i came up with the solution as follows:

**Solution :**
***Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection -> Active Provider as "Direct".***

And then tried to upload the project on lambda by using the same steps, and it worked for me.
Hope this will help you too.